# Change element background on scroll, based on current section and performance optimized

Tags: javascript

The idea is to change the `.wrapper` background depending on the current section. Unfortunately, there are some limitations. I need to change it based on the current `window.scrollTop` and `section.offsetTop` and **NOT** on which section is in the viewport at the moment. ([IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) will not work)

It will be something like scrollSpy, but I am not able to loop over all of the sections in every scroll event because of performance reasons. Also, I am using a virtual scroll plugin for smooth scrolling, which makes even more calculations on scroll.

To the code I have till the moment:

My sections look like this:

```
<section class="intro"
  data-bg="#ffffff"
  data-color="#1A1919"
>
  Section content goes here
</section>
```

I have an array of objects. In each object, I have the node element and its top.

```
const sections = [
  {
    el: section.intro, // Node
    top: 1224 // Number
  },
  ....
]
```

I can take the scrollTop from the plugin on scroll. So the code for now looks like:

```
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

const changeBg = (scrollTop, sections) => {
  sections.map(({ el, top }) => {
    const bg = el.getAttribute('data-bg');
    const color = el.getAttribute('data-color');

    if (top < scrollTop + window.innerHeight) {
      console.log(bg);
      wrapper.style.backgroundColor = bg;
      wrapper.style.color = color;
    }
  });
};

myCustomPluginForScroll.on('scroll', e => {
  const { y } = e.scroll;

  changeBg(y, sections);
});
```

The problems are:

1. I loop all of the sections on every scroll event (which is multiplied by many from the plugin to make smooth scrolling) and it causes lag on scroll;
2. As I scroll more downwards, more and more sections become valid for the condition `top < y + window.innerHeight` which changes the wrapper background even more times per scroll.

I can't use debouncer to make number of calls of `changeBg` lower, because of the smooth scroll plugin.

**To the question:**

How can I make call of `changeBg` only once when new section is added/removed from the condition of `top < y + window.innerHeight` and take the bg/color attributes only on the last added/removed section.

Attaching screenshot with log of `bg` with 6 sections and scrolled to the bottom of the site. That way, on every single scroll I have 6 changes of wrapper's background.

[image: screenshot from last console.log of bg]

Comment: you can tag the active section the first time then test the if the section is already changed before calling your actual change logic. eg. `addEventListener('scroll', e => { if (!sectionToChange.classList.contains('your-active-class`) { // run your code...}

Comment: Good suggestion @pilchard, but the code should work when you scroll back to the top, changing the background related to the current section's `data-bg` attribute.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, just differentiate scroll direction and set/clear the recolor accordingly.